# How to index data frame column by a variable?

Tags: r, types, dataframe

As an example, I want a function that will iterate over the columns in a dataframe and print out each column's data type (e.g., "numeric", "integer", "character", etc)

Without a variable I know I can do `class(df$MyColumn)` and get the data type.  How can I change it so "MyColumn" is a variable?

What I'm trying is

```
f <- function(df) {

 for(column in names(df)) {
   columnClass = class(df[column])
   print(columnClass)
 }

}
```

But this just prints out `[1] "data.frame"` for each column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a comma before `column`:

```
for(column in names(df)) {
   columnClass = class(df[,column])
   print(columnClass)
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Since a data frame is simply a list, you can loop over the columns using `lapply` and apply the `class` function to each column:

```
lapply(df, class)
```

To address the previously unspoken concerns in User's comment.... if you build a function that does *whatever* it is that you hope to a column, then this *will* succeed:

```
func <- function(col) {print(class(col))}
lapply(df, func)
```

It's really mostly equivalent to:

```
 for(col in names(df) ) { print(class(df[[col]]))}
```

And there would not be an unneeded 'colClass' variable cluttering up the .GlobalEnv.

Comment: Although I see the elegance of this, and it does solve the example I provided, it doesn't actually answer my question, whereas the answer by smu does.  In reality, I need to do more than just print out each column.

Answer (score 1):

Much as DWin suggested

```
apply(df,2,class)
```

but you say you want to do more with each coloumn?
What do you want to do. Try to avoid abstract examples. 
In case it helps

```
apply(df,2,mean)
apply(df,2,sd)
```

or something more complicated

```
apply(df,2,function(x){s = c(summary(x)["Mean"], summary(x)["Median"], sd(x))})
```

Note that the summary function gives you most of this functionality anyway, but this is just an example. any function can be place inside of an apply and iterated over the cols of a matrix or dataframe. that function can be as complex or as simple as you need it to be.

Comment: `apply` will only provide the correct answer if all the columns have the same class.  This is because `apply` is meant to work on matrices and arrays, which cannot mix types.  In your answer, `df` will be converted to a matrix before `class` is applied to each column.  E.g. `apply(iris,2,class)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **colwise** function of the **plyr** package to transform any function into a column wise function.  This is a wrapper for **lapply**.

```
library(plyr)

colwise.print.class<-colwise(.fun=function(col) {print(class(col))})

colwise.print.class(df)
```

You can view the function created with

```
print(colwise.print.class)
```